# Finding a bug using Xcode - attempt to insert nil value

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging, xcode4.3

I am getting a random bug in my app, which is causing it to crash. The problem I am facing is XCode doesn't tell me where the crash is happening only the below information. Can someone tell me how I can find out where I might be able to find the problem within the code? It must be crashing at the same point as when the app does crash it always shows the below.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary
>   setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: 0)'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x381e48bf 0x37d301e5 0x381e47b9 0x381e47db 0x381516bb 0x9237b 0x91121 0x8f0c5 0x8abc1 0x37b9d 0x8b68f
>   0x3550850f 0x381b0577 0x3813c0cf 0x3547c3fb 0x3547dc2b 0x8d005
>   0x3814322b 0x34495 0x32e31 0x3372d 0x30a59 0x3813e435 0x7b1df 0x7b88d
>   0x79e25 0x31ca650f 0x31ca5f01 0x31c8c4ed 0x31c8bd2d 0x37f12df3
>   0x381b8553 0x381b84f5 0x381b7343 0x3813a4dd 0x3813a3a5 0x37f11fcd
>   0x31cba743 0x89e8b 0x24a4) terminate called throwing an
>   exception(lldb)

Comment: the error says that your are trying to set a nil value in your dictionary

Comment: To find a bug you can add break point or eanable NSZombie or add execption break point

Comment: It looks like you have symbols turned off. Perhaps you are building for release and not for development?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you turned on **exception breakpoints**? Click the **+** at the bottom left of the Breakpoint Navigator, then select **Add Exception Breakpont**.

[image]

You can right click the breakpoint to edit it…

[image]

This will cause the code to stop at the point where the error occurs.

Answer (score 10):

There is a solution that I usually use on my projects, setting up some special breakpoint.
To do that:

1. Open XCode
2. Goes to "View -> Navigators -> Show Breakpoint Navigators"

Now add some new breakpoints clicking the "+" button:

- Add exception breakpoint
- Add Symbolic breakpoint with symbol `[NSException raise]`
- Add Symbolic breakpoint with symbol `objc_exception_throw`

Run again your project, application will stop on the line that is causing your problems.

Comment: Why is this not on by default!?

Answer (score 0):

error is evident enough. in any of your line, where you are setting some object for dictionary, you key is nill, which is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you are using setObject: forKey Method to NSDictionary just make it NSMutableDictionary then try this method you can't assign value for NSDictionary like you are trying it's only for NSMutableDictionary.

i hope you will get my point what i am try to say.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if([myDictionary objectForKey:@"string"]!= nil && [myDictionary objectForKey:@"string"]!= Nil) { }
```